# Wordpress search form and search result through ACF field in custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

So I think I'm making life hard for myself.

I have a search field on my website that I have split into 3 e.g:

```
<input type="text" name="part1" />
<input type="text" name="part2" />
<input type="text" name="part3" />
```

On my results page I create the search string e.g:

```
$searchstring = $part1.'-'.$part2.'-'.$part3;
```

The process then is to search the database for my custom field that has a value of `$searchstring`

I found a search function https://gist.github.com/jserrao/d8b20a6c5c421b9d2a51 there which I think's rather close to what I'm trying to achieve but I'm not really sure how to implement everything in.

My data roughly looks like this:

```
(taxonomy) product_cat - (name) Category 1 - (custom field) gc_number - (value I need to search) 77-999-77
(taxonomy) product_cat - (name) Category 2 - (custom field) gc_number - (value I need to search) 73-333-73
(taxonomy) product_cat - (name) Category 3 - (custom field) gc_number - (value I need to search) 76-666-76
```

I then need to display the `product_cat` name to the user.

Hopefully this makes some sense and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I asked this question on Stack Exchange - Wordpress Development and got a fantastic answer from Kieran McClung. His answer works perfectly for me and is copied below.

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="acf-search" action="<?php site_url(); ?>">
...

<input type="text" name="part1" />
<input type="text" name="part2" />
<input type="text" name="part3" />

<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>


<?php
// Results page

// Might be worth checking to make sure these exist before doing the query.
$part_1 = $_GET['part1'];
$part_2 = $_GET['part2'];
$part_3 = $_GET['part3'];
$search_string = $part_1 . '-' . $part_2 . '-' . $part_3;

// Get all product categories
$categories = get_terms( 'product_cat' );
$counter = 0;

// Loop through categories
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {

    // Get custom field
    $gc_number = get_field( 'gc_number', $category );

    // If field matches search string, echo name
    if ( $gc_number == $search_string ) {
        // Update counter for use later
        $counter++;
        echo $category->name;
    }
}

// $counter only increases if custom field matches $search_string.
// If still 0 at this point, no matches were found.
if ( $counter == 0 ) {
    echo 'Sorry, no results found';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/) documentation

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'meta_key'      => 'color',
    'meta_value'    => 'red'
));
```

This example shows the arguments to find all posts where a custom field called ‘color’ has a value of ‘red’. In your case, u should use `gc_number` for meta_key and `$searchstring` for meta_value. Then u can use `get_the_terms()` to define, which category terms do the posts belong to.

Comment: Hi thanks for that. I've had a look at that and what's throwing me is the queried post type which is set as post in the example. However my custom field is set on a taxonomy (product_cat). Do I just change post to taxonomy or product_cat or something?