# wordpress, acf and adding a search field in media, searching ONLY the custom field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Wordpress and the Advanced Custom Field Plugin.

For attachments I added a customfield, containing two fields, one select and one checkbox.

Now I want to add two searchfields in the Admin "media" - Page, which search only in the given acf field, not the other fields.

I have found a plugin (ACF: Better Search) that makes adjustments to the search, but customises the entire query and includes the custom fields.
However, as the terms in the custom fields are quite general, the terms can also appear in other fields such as title or description. However, searches should only be carried out in the custom fields, not in the other fields.
Some other plugins (WPSearch*, Ivory Search, Better Search) don't use the acf Plugin, so don't help either.

Is there a plugin or a simple way to integrate this yourself?

I also found [Wordpress search form and search result through ACF field in custom taxonomy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41716882/wordpress-search-form-and-search-result-through-acf-field-in-custom-taxonomy) , but it does not help me either. To modify the admin/upload.php seems to be wrong, but I don't see hooks or listener, which can be used to add functionality...

I haven't switched to PHP that long ago, and have mainly worked in the Symfony framework. I'm still struggling with WordPress...